# Pattern.complie breaks XStream

Tags: java, regex, eclipse, serialization, xstream

I'm observing really weird behavior from the XStream library while reading the file it generated and using Patter.compile on the results
When ran it gives null pointer exception ***but it works fine if I run it step by step in a debug mode***.
I'v narrowed it down to Pattern.complie If I just reads  value to a string variable it works fine, if I use Pattern.complie(".*") withing the unmarshal method  it works fine too
I use Java 7 and XStream 1.4.4
I think this is due reader.getAttribute("key") returning null but not when debugging
Any idea why is this happning ?
Here is what I have:
My class

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
public class A {
private Pattern key;
ArrayList<A> subTree;
public A(HierarchicalStreamReader reader, UnmarshallingContext context){
    this.key=Pattern.compile(reader.getAttribute("key"));
            // String a = reader.getAttribute("key") - Works fine
            // this.key=Pattern.compile(a) - Breaks   
    subTree=new ArrayList<A>();
    reader.moveDown();
    while(reader.hasMoreChildren()) {
        subTree.add(new A(reader,context));
    }
    reader.moveUp();
}
}
```

XStream converter class

```
public class AConverter implements Converter {
    public boolean canConvert(Class clazz) {
        return A.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
    }

    public void marshal(Object value, HierarchicalStreamWriter writer, MarshallingContext context) {

    }

    public Object unmarshal(HierarchicalStreamReader reader, UnmarshallingContext context) {
        reader.moveDown();
        A n = new A(reader,context);
        reader.moveUp();
        return n;
    }
```

}

Test case

```
public void testA() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
    XStream xstream = new XStream();
    xstream.alias("MessageFieldMappings", A.class);
    xstream.registerConverter(new AConverter());
    ObjectInputStream in = xstream.createObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("test1.xml"));
    A rootNode = (A) in.readObject();
    in.close();

}
```

Test file (test1.xml)

```
<object-stream>
<MessageFieldMappings>
<RootMapping>
  <FieldMap key=".*">
    <FieldMap key="A.*">
      <FieldMap key="AB.*"/>
      <FieldMap key="AC.*"/>
    </FieldMap>
    <FieldMap key="D.*"/>
  </FieldMap>
</RootMapping>
</MessageFieldMappings>
</object-stream>
```

The error I get

```
com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: null : null
---- Debugging information ----
cause-exception     : java.lang.NullPointerException
cause-message       : null
class               : nz.orion.monkPraser.praser.fieldConverter.A
required-type       : nz.orion.monkPraser.praser.fieldConverter.A
converter-type      : nz.orion.monkPraser.praser.fieldConverter.AConverter
path                : /MessageFieldMappings/RootMapping
line number         : 3
version             : null
-------------------------------
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:79)
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clue is in

```
path                : /MessageFieldMappings/RootMapping
line number         : 3
```

You've aliased `MessageFieldMappings` to class `A`, so when it sees a `MessageFieldMappings` it will call the converter, which will `moveDown` to the `RootMapping` element and attempt to extract a `key` attribute from that. It doesn't have one, hence the NPE.

You need an extra level of moveDown/Up in the converter:

```
reader.moveDown(); // RootMapping
reader.moveDown(); // First FieldMap
A n = new A(reader,context);
reader.moveUp();
reader.moveUp();
return n;
```

Comment: Yes its quite obvious really I don't know how I missed it. Thanks a lot for your time! I guess my debugger might be ignoring NullPointer